# Is the Ouroboros Praos protocol proprietary?

Tags: ouroboros

The [slots and epochs](https://cardano-foundation.gitbook.io/stake-pool-course/lessons/introduction/about-cardano#slots-and-epochs) section of the Cardano Stake Pool Course states that the Ouroboros [Praos protocol](https://iohk.io/en/research/library/papers/ouroboros-praosan-adaptively-securesemi-synchronous-proof-of-stake-protocol/) is proprietary.

Is this correct and, if so, is there a reason why this central part of the implementation needs to be proprietary?

Comment: Great catch! I have no idea how the word "proprietary" found its way in there. It's wrong, of course. I've just merged your pull request. BTW we moved this old course to the new developer portal that is being built. A lot of things are already improved, but if someone wants to contribute to the SPO category, please get in touch with me.

Comment: @adatainment I'd be interested in contributing.  Also - it would be good to see whether Chris Moreton's [fork of plutus-pioneer-program](https://github.com/chris-moreton/plutus-pioneer-program) can be merged, he is doing a great job of documenting the lectures: https://plutus-pioneer-program.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct!

[The ledger specifications](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs) are licensed under Apache License 2.0 and [the paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/573.pdf) is also open to public.

Comment: To be fair, the source states "The Cardano blockchain uses the proprietary Ouroboros Praos protocol to facilitate consensus on the chain."

Comment: Yes, the source is wrong. Or probably the wording is wrong.

Comment: I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/stake-pool-school-handbook/pull/46) to get the source corrected

Comment: And the CF merged it right away! CF rocks.